# How to calculate degrees of freedom in a Chi-Squared Test?

Tags: chi-squared-test, degrees-of-freedom

I'm looking to calculate the degrees of freedom (df) for a chi squared test which has one dependent group with 3 categories and one dependent group with 4 categories. What would the df be?

Answer (score 3):

When the data are in a contingency table, the formula to use is $df = (r-1)(c-1)$ where $r$ is the number of rows and $c$ is the number of columns. So in this particular case the answer will be 6.

Comment: Does this answer your question ? If so please consider marking it as the accepted answer. If not, please let us know why. Also, if you haven't already, please consider upvoting it. –